# Changing cloud endpoints root url does not appear to work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use root parameter of the `@Api` annotation to `https://appid.appspot.com/myapi`. This is reflected in the api configs, but both on the development and production server the api isn't working, yielding 404 errors when I try to access the API.

Is it possible to change the root url to something that doesn't start with `_ah` or is this currently a requirement for Cloud Endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path must be under `/_ah` currently.